# How to extract all visible text from a webpage using R

Tags: r, rselenium, rcurl

I require the visible text of this page: https://www.americanexpress.com/ca/en/credit-cards/simply-cash-preferred/

At first, I thought RSelenium would work. But I couldn't figure out how to get **all** of the text that is visible.

```
library("RSelenium")
library("rvest")

remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://www.americanexpress.com/ca/en/credit-cards/simply-cash-preferred")
remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()
# or
remDr$findElement(using='css selector',"body")$getElementText()
```

next, I read about getURLContent

```
library("RCurl")
library("XML")

url <- "https://www.americanexpress.com/ca/en/credit-cards/simply-cash-preferred"
x <- getURLContent(url)
x
```

but received this message when trying:

```
[1] "Found. Redirecting to /ca/en/credit-cards/simply-cash-preferred/"
attr(,"Content-Type")
                  charset 
"text/plain"      "utf-8"
```

I'm not sure how to obtain content of this particular page using getURLContent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the page has a good deal of javascript, a combination of Rselenium, rvest, and htm2txt is helpful. The function `htm2txt::htm2txt()` will take care (i.e. parse out or remove) of lots of javascript formatting snippets that would be difficult to exclude using plain rvest.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(htm2txt)
library(tidyverse)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4545L, verbose=TRUE)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate("https://www.americanexpress.com/ca/en/credit-cards/simply-cash-preferred")

captured_text <- 
  remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html(encoding = "UTF-8") %>% 
  html_node(xpath = "//body") %>% 
  as.character() %>% 
  htm2txt::htm2txt()

captured_text
[1] "Skip to content\n\nMenuMenu\n\nThe following navigation element is controlled via arrow keys followed by tab\n\nMy Account\nMy Account\n\nPersonal Accounts\n\n• Account Summary\n\n• View Statement\n\n• Manage Account\n\n• Make a Payment\n\n• Manage Pre-Authorized Payment\n\n• Add Someone to Your Account\n\nBusiness Accounts\n\n• Business Account Summary\n\n• American Express @Work\n\n• Merchant Services\n\nOnline Services\n\n• Register for Online Services\n\n• Activate Your Card\n\n• American Express App\n\n• Manage Account Alerts\n\n• Sign Up for Email Offers\n\n• Online-Only Statements\n\nHelp & Support\n\n• Forgot User ID or Password?\n\n• Support 24/7\n\n• Welcome Centre\n\n• Ways to Pay\n\n• Security Centre\n\nCanadaChange Country\n\nEnglish\n\n• Français\n\nCards\nCards\n\nPersonal Cards\n\n• View All Cards\n\n• Cash Back Credit Cards\n\n• Flexible Rewards Cards\n\n• No Annual Fee Cards\n\n• Co-Branded Cards\n\n• Travel Cards\n\nFeatured Cards\n\n• The American Express Aeroplan Reserve Card\n\n• The Cobalt Card\n\n• The SimplyCash Preferred Card\n\n• The Choice Card..."
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not all of the visible text. For example, the text, "Earn up to" is not part of `captured_text`. "Earn up to $500 cash back in the first 4 months1" is the heading of the first box at the top of the page.

Comment: Very interestingly, I do not get ""Earn up to $500 cash back in the first 4 months1"", but rather "Earn 10% cash back in your first 4 months (up to $400 cash back)1". My guess is that depending on the cookies and IP, the javascript is generating custom content/offers.

Comment: So your code is fine, it's just that the page really does change? An A/B test going on perhaps?

Comment: It seems plausible to me. But if the content is very dynamic, then a simpler code from a cookieless client that does not need Selenium might get you consistent results:
Simply run: 
`htm2txt::gettxt(URL = "https://www.americanexpress.com/ca/en/credit-cards/simply-cash-preferred")`

Comment: I notice neither method captures text that lives in the "+" surrounded by a circle. How can that be done? Ideally using a method that obtains consistent results.